# Generic XML Serializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to implement generic XML serializer as described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/field_notes/archive/2008/06/19/the-last-datacontract-serializer-on-earth.aspx

```
internal static class GenericXmlSerializer<T>
{
    public static void WriteObject(T outputObject, string outputFile)
    {
        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.Serialize(writer, outputObject);
        }
    }

    public static T ReadObject(string objectData)
    {
        T deserializedObject = default(T);

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader);
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            deserializedObject = (T)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            xmlReader.Close();
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

I then want to call it, but I don't want to hardcode my object types (example hardcoded):

```
GenericXmlSerializer<MyObjectType>.WriteObject((MyObjectType)data.Payload ,stream);
```

How do I get those object types at runtime?
e.g. something like:

```
GenericXmlSerializer<typeof(data.Payload)>.WriteObject((MyObjectType)data.Payload ,stream);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `T` from class, Then you can use as

```
GenericXmlSerializer.WriteObject(anyObject,"a.xml");
```

---

```
internal static class GenericXmlSerializer
{
    public static void WriteObject<T>(T outputObject, string outputFile)
    {
        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.Serialize(writer, outputObject);
        }
    }

    public static T ReadObject<T>(string objectData)
    {
        T deserializedObject = default(T);

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader);
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            deserializedObject = (T)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            xmlReader.Close();
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I then get a runtime error: <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @DermFrench I edited the answer. This is not about the code, it is about *XmlSerializer can not serialize/deserialize anonymous objects*. Try other objects...

Comment: @DermFrench If you need a more flexible serializer I would suggest Json.Net (If Xml is not a must)

Comment: Funny I've just been looking at Json.Net, seems so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

a generic XML Serializer i wrote vb.net

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Friend Module XML

    Public Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal filename As String) As T

        Dim result As T

        Using reader As New StreamReader(filename, True)

            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
            result = CType(serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(reader)), T)

        End Using

        Return result

    End Function

    Public Sub Serialize(Of T)(ByVal filename As String, ByVal obj As T, ByVal qualifiedNames As XmlQualifiedName(), ByVal encoding As Encoding)

        Dim namespaces As New XmlSerializerNamespaces(qualifiedNames)
        Dim settings = New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Encoding = encoding

        Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))

        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings)

            writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, namespaces)

        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```